# aave staking I cannot withdraw usdc tokens earned as rewards in my smart contract

Tags: aave

```
function stake(address _asset, uint256 _amount) public {
    require(_amount > 0, "Amount must be greater than 0");
    IERC20(_asset).safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount);

    depositedBalance[_asset] += _amount;

    IERC20(_asset).safeIncreaseAllowance(
        address(aaveIPool),
         _amount);

    aaveIPool.supply(_asset, _amount, address(this), 0);


    totalInvested += _amount;
    userInvestments[_asset] += _amount;
    
    emit Stake(_asset, _amount);
          
}

function getAUSDCBalance(address _user) public view returns (uint256) {
(uint256 totalBalance, , , , , , , , ) = aaveIPoolDataProvider.getUserReserveData(address(USDC), address(this));
uint256 userInvestment = userInvestments[_user];
uint256 userBalance = userInvestment * totalBalance / totalInvested;
return userBalance;
```

}

```
function unstake(address _asset, uint256 _amount) public {
    require(_amount > 0, "Amount must be greater than 0");

   //getting total balance (deposited + rewards)
   (uint256 totalBalance, , , , , , , ,  ) = 
   aaveIPoolDataProvider
     .getUserReserveData(_asset, address(this));
    require(_amount <= totalBalance, "Insufficiant balance");

    
    require(
        aaveIPool.withdraw(_asset, _amount, address(this)) > 0,
        "0 whithdrawn from AAVE!"
    );
      
        totalInvested -= _amount;
        userInvestments[_asset] -= _amount;
        depositedBalance[_asset] -= _amount;

        IERC20(_asset).safeTransfer(msg.sender, _amount);
         
        emit Unstake(_asset, _amount);
    
}
```

**everything is working properly but I cannot withdraw the usdc balances earned from the aave pool. where could I be making the mistake. thanks for your help**